# BCP: Unable to use Native formats while exporting

Tags: sql-server, bcp

This is how I am using the BCP:

-- Generating format file in native content (-n)

**`bcp Sales.dbo.Num format nul -n -f D:\Format.fmt -T  -S .\sqlexpress`**

-- Exporting the table using above format file

**`bcp Sales.dbo.Num out D:\FactNum.csv -f D:\Format.fmt -T -S .\sqlexpress`**

But whatever I do the output .csv is always gibberish.

P.S.

1. It's working well if char version of format files (with -c param)
2. I have tried xml native version of format file but of no help
3. Gone through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2014) and basic BCP documentation on MSDN

Suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

"gibberish" as you put it, is what you get when you use native (-n) data. The data is written to the file in SQL Server's native format, not ascii text. I believe you want to see ASCII text? If so, that is what the character (-c) option is for.

The use of a format file has nothing to do with the "format" of the file in this regard.

There is the format of the data (set by the -c, -n and other options) and then there is the format of the columns... that is defined by the format file if you so choose.

You are exporting data in native format, but you want it to look like data that is not in SQL native format. SQL native format is not for consumption by human beings... it's made to be read by a SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But little confused here. By native format what I understand is native formats of my exported columns will remain intact, say float will remain as float. MSDN does talks about these SQL mapping types to native exported type. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Secondly, taking your words, if native really produces output in un-readable format than how useful it can be if none other than SQL is able to decode. 

P.S. - I did tried to view this via python, Databricks. It's gibberish everywhere.

Comment: BCP'ing from SQL in native mode is useless for any destination other then SQL, it's true as you say. One of native modes purpose is to eliminate possible errors in translation from one "language" to another. However this does harshly restrict portability.  You're stuck with SQL Server if using native mode. As for native format and what does it mean, it is true that with native format you keep data in it's native, sql formats. However, to do this, the data must not be "translated" out of the sql proprietary format (which is gobbildy-gook to human eyes) and into ASCII/text.